# I have been trying to install tensorflow on gpu, and when I tried to test if it works this strange error message came out. How do I fix this:

Tags: python, tensorflow

**I installed:**

1. tensorflow 2.10
2. python 3.10 in conda
3. cuda 11.2
4. cuDNN 8.1
   **I am using:**
5. NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070
6. windows 10

error message:
**2023-01-03 18:26:00.103847: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 5453 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 8.6**

Comment: That is not an error message, it is confirmation that the GPU works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it means you are using the gpu.i'm dealing with similar issues. I want to communicate.

```
print('GPU name: ', tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

Comment: Ok, I will try to find something on the net

Comment: I downloaded 11.2 again.    from here -> https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.2.0-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exenetwork

Comment: Are you using 8.1.0 or 8.1.1 for cudnn ?

Comment: GPU name:  [] I am getting this result.

Comment: I am usin cuDNN 8.1.1

Comment: OK so i tried to run some code an this is what the error looked liek: 2023-01-03 19:05:17.478505: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

Comment: What command did you use for cuda 11.2 ?

Comment: It is not solved I just found some random code on git hub to see if it would run from gpu but it did not.

Comment: @PeterJurák You do not have a problem, the "error" in your question is not an error. What makes you think the GPU is not being used?

Comment: I think it is saying that it is using cpu.

Comment: @PeterJurák CPU is always used, again, you do not have a problem, the message in your question confirms that the GPU is detected by Tensorflow.

Comment: Oh, okay. I am really new to this so sorry if my questions seemed stupid and thank you for your guidence

Comment: What command did you use for cuda 11.2 ?

Comment: you can write the answer under the question on my page

Comment: The question is not stupid. I'm new at  and I understand you very well:)